# Why is it true that $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)=dx_q(e_i)? $

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The following is the definition of Riemannian metrics in *Riemannian Geometry* by do Carmo:

[image]

I don't quite understand the underlined sentence.

In the book, the following is the definition of "differentials":

[image]

Here is my **question**:

> How does one get
>   $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)=dx_q(0,...,1,...,0)?
> $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $x:U\subseteq \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \phi(U)$ is a diffeomorphism with respect to the smooth structure $U$ inherits from $\mathbb R^n$ and the smooth structure $\phi(U)$ inherits from $M$. Hence: $$dx_p:T_pU=\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow T_{x(p)}\phi(U)=T_{x(p)}M,$$ is an isomorphism for every $p\in U$. Therefore you can transport the cannonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$ to a basis of $T_{x(p)}M$ setting $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(p):=dx_p(e_j),$$ where $e_j$ is the $j$-th cannonical vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you saying that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(p)$ is just a notation and "=" should be understood as "defined as"?

Comment: You're welcome. Yep, that's defined this way.

Answer (score 2):

It is only a notation, you are defining the vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)$, not saying that it is equal to something. If you prefer you can simply say that the map $q\mapsto\langle dx_qv,dx_qw\rangle$ is differentiable for any $v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you understand what the derivative matrix of a multivariable, multidimensional map between Euclidian spaces looks like: http://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)=dx_q(0,...,1,...,0)$ is basically saying take the $i$-th "column" of the "derivative matrix" $dx_{q}$ (which would represent a basis vector in this isomorphism), except we are not necessarily embedding $M$ in a suitably large Euclidean space with the map $x$, so one shouldn't think of it as the derivative matrix, but instead as a mapping on the tangent space (that's why I put quotes on "derivative matrix").

Answer (score 0):

Lots of identifications are made. To see what is really going on in the identity 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)=dx_q(e_i)\tag{*}$$ it is instructive to go back to the definitions symbol by symbol.

First of all, by definition, the left hand side
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(q)=\alpha'(0)\in T_qM
$$
where $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ is the $i$-th coordinate curve on $M_2$:
$$
\alpha(t)=x(te_i)\tag{1}
$$
and 
$$
\alpha'(0)(f):=(f\circ\alpha)'(0)\quad\textrm{for all }f\in C^\infty(M). 
$$

For the right hand side, note that $M_1=U$ is a manifold with the natural structure on $U$. On can consider $(U,y)$ with $y=id_{\mathbb{R}^n}|_U$ as a chart for $M_1$. Then $\varphi:=x$ can be identified as a map between manifolds 
$$
\varphi:M_1\to M_2:=x(U)\subset M.
$$
Now let $p=x^{-1}(q)$. Then $dx_q=d\varphi_p$ as in (2.7). In (*), $e_i$ is identify with
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}(p)=\gamma'(0)\in T_PM_1
$$
where $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M_1$ is the $i$-th coordinate curve on $M_1$:
$$
\gamma(t)=y(te_i)=te_i\tag{2}
$$
by the definition of $y$.

Now, 
$$
dx_q(e_i)=d\varphi_p(\gamma'(0))=(\varphi\circ\gamma)'(0)=(x\circ\gamma)'(0).
$$
To show (*), one only need to notice that
$$
\alpha'(0)=(x\circ\gamma)'(0)
$$
since $\alpha=x\circ\gamma$ which follows from (1) and (2).